# Always getting the first row of the table when using dapper

Tags: dapper

When I am using dapper I am keep getting the first row of the table eventhough I am trying to Pass specific ID but i am still getting the first row from the table. What is it I am missing?   I checked in the sql profiler and found that id is not being sent to the stored procedure and all the data is returend. I tired many things but dont know why id is not being passed.

```
public Setting GetConfigurationPerIdy(string id)
{
    return Run(conn => conn.Query<Setting>("spProc_GetSettingById",
        new {id}).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with regular ADO.NET, the default assumption is `CommandType.CommandText`; if the command you are executing is a stored procedure, *you need to tell it*:

```
..., new {id}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Otherwise, it is functionally identical to:

```
declare @id int = 7; -- or whatever
exec spProc_GetSettingById; -- note that we didn't add the parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **FirstOrDefault()** from your code, As it will return only first row from the table else default null.